# Error: onSubmit doesn't work on reactjs jsx render method

Tags: node.js, reactjs, onsubmit

I'm trying to create a form inside a react component on node server but my onSubmit attr isn't being compiled. any thoughts why?
Here is my code:

```
/** @jsx React.DOM **/

var React = require('react');


module.exports = UserForm = React.createClass({
    handleSubmit: function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log("teste");
    },

    render : function () {
        return (
            <div className="container">
                <form onSubmit= { this.handleSubmit } className="section">

                    <button className="btn waves-effect waves-light" type="submit">
                        Entrar
                        <i className="mdi-content-send right"></i>
                    </button>
                </form>
            </div>
        )
    }
});
```

and the output for this rendered code is this :

```
<div class="container" data-reactid=".1vxqgp72xa8" data-react-checksum="-1342114635">

    <form class="section" data-reactid=".1vxqgp72xa8.0">
        <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light" type="submit" data-reactid=".1vxqgp72xa8.0.1">
             <span data-reactid=".1vxqgp72xa8.0.1.0">Entrar</span>
             <i class="mdi-content-send right" data-reactid=".1vxqgp72xa8.0.1.1"></i>
        </button><div class="preloader-wrapper big active" data-reactid=".1vxqgp72xa8.0.2">   
    </form>
</div>
```

this may be a silly error, can someone help me finding it?

THanks you all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple enough, you aren't providing a callback. It should look like this:

```
<form onSubmit={ this.handleSubmit } className="section">
```

**Edit:**
After a little discussion in the comments, it became clear you weren't mounting the app on the front-end after delivering the server rendered html to the browser. After the page has loaded call this:

```
React.render(React.createElement(UserForm, {}), domElement);
```

Comment: just updated my question with your answer, but it's still not working, I read something about problems with server side rendering of events. could this be something related to it?

Comment: What about using <input type="submit" /> instead of a button?

Comment: Also, if you're rendering the app server-side, are you also mounting the app client-side? You need to do both. Add a componentDidMount handler and make sure the app is running.

Comment: nope =/, I think the problem have something to do with the fact that the onSubmit event is not even being rendered to the final html.

Comment: you are right, the componentDidMount is never called. what do I need to do in order to mount it?

Comment: No, it doesn't render the function in the html. I think you need to run React.render(UserForm, domElement) to actually start the app on the front-end.

Comment: thanks @Shawn I could solve the problem now, running React.render.

Comment: Could you please write your answer in a queue so I can mark it as right?